# Hide a Centered Logo on Mobile Viewport

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I am working on a site and the logo is centered on the navbar at the bottom of the page as list item. When the site collapses to mobile i want to hide it. I've tried display:none and hidden but cant figure it out. If you can see an easier way to have a bottom nav that scrolls up with a centered logo I will take it lol

```js
(function($) {
  var defaults = {
      topSpacing: 0,
      bottomSpacing: 0,
      className: 'is-sticky',
      wrapperClassName: 'sticky-wrapper',
      center: false,
      getWidthFrom: '',
      responsiveWidth: false
    },
    $window = $(window),
    $document = $(document),
    sticked = [],
    windowHeight = $window.height(),
    scroller = function() {
      var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
        documentHeight = $document.height(),
        dwh = documentHeight - windowHeight,
        extra = (scrollTop > dwh) ? dwh - scrollTop : 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < sticked.length; i++) {
        var s = sticked[i],
          elementTop = s.stickyWrapper.offset().top,
          etse = elementTop - s.topSpacing - extra;

        if (scrollTop <= etse) {
          if (s.currentTop !== null) {
            s.stickyElement
              .css('position', '')
              .css('top', '');
            s.stickyElement.trigger('sticky-end', [s]).parent().removeClass(s.className);
            s.currentTop = null;
          }
        }
        else {
          var newTop = documentHeight - s.stickyElement.outerHeight()
            - s.topSpacing - s.bottomSpacing - scrollTop - extra;
          if (newTop < 0) {
            newTop = newTop + s.topSpacing;
          } else {
            newTop = s.topSpacing;
          }
          if (s.currentTop != newTop) {
            s.stickyElement
              .css('position', 'fixed')
              .css('top', newTop);

            if (typeof s.getWidthFrom !== 'undefined') {
              s.stickyElement.css('width', $(s.getWidthFrom).width());
            }

            s.stickyElement.trigger('sticky-start', [s]).parent().addClass(s.className);
            s.currentTop = newTop;
          }
        }
      }
    },
    resizer = function() {
      windowHeight = $window.height();

      for (var i = 0; i < sticked.length; i++) {
        var s = sticked[i];
        if (typeof s.getWidthFrom !== 'undefined' && s.responsiveWidth === true) {
          s.stickyElement.css('width', $(s.getWidthFrom).width());
        }
      }
    },
    methods = {
      init: function(options) {
        var o = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
          var stickyElement = $(this);

          var stickyId = stickyElement.attr('id');
          var wrapperId = stickyId ? stickyId + '-' + defaults.wrapperClassName : defaults.wrapperClassName 
          var wrapper = $('<div></div>')
            .attr('id', stickyId + '-sticky-wrapper')
            .addClass(o.wrapperClassName);
          stickyElement.wrapAll(wrapper);

          if (o.center) {
            stickyElement.parent().css({width:stickyElement.outerWidth(),marginLeft:"auto",marginRight:"auto"});
          }

          if (stickyElement.css("float") == "right") {
            stickyElement.css({"float":"none"}).parent().css({"float":"right"});
          }

          var stickyWrapper = stickyElement.parent();
          stickyWrapper.css('height', stickyElement.outerHeight());
          sticked.push({
            topSpacing: o.topSpacing,
            bottomSpacing: o.bottomSpacing,
            stickyElement: stickyElement,
            currentTop: null,
            stickyWrapper: stickyWrapper,
            className: o.className,
            getWidthFrom: o.getWidthFrom,
            responsiveWidth: o.responsiveWidth
          });
        });
      },
      update: scroller,
      unstick: function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
          var unstickyElement = $(this);

          var removeIdx = -1;
          for (var i = 0; i < sticked.length; i++)
          {
            if (sticked[i].stickyElement.get(0) == unstickyElement.get(0))
            {
                removeIdx = i;
            }
          }
          if(removeIdx != -1)
          {
            sticked.splice(removeIdx,1);
            unstickyElement.unwrap();
            unstickyElement.removeAttr('style');
          }
        });
      }
    };

  // should be more efficient than using $window.scroll(scroller) and $window.resize(resizer):
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scroller, false);
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizer, false);
  } else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onscroll', scroller);
    window.attachEvent('onresize', resizer);
  }

  $.fn.sticky = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.sticky');
    }
  };

  $.fn.unstick = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method ) {
      return methods.unstick.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.sticky');
    }

  };
  $(function() {
    setTimeout(scroller, 0);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.section-menu{
 z-index: 9999;
}

.navbar-default{
 background: #141414;
 border: 0px;
 border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 30px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus{
 color: #7f1f1f;
}
.main-nav{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
    color: #fcb027;
    background-color: transparent;
}
#navbar-primary .navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar-primary .navbar-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#navbar-primary .navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
   .logo{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".main-nav">
  <section id="section-banner">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="banner-content text-center">
      <h2 class="title">
       <div class="line-top"></div>
       Twitch Streamer & Web Designer
       <div class="line-btm"></div> 
      </h2>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Learn More</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Navagation Starts -->
  <section class="section-menu">
   <div id="navbar-primary" class="navbar navbar-default main-nav" role="navigation" >
    <div class="container" >
     <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type= "button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse">
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
     </div><!-- navbar-header end -->
     <!-- main nav  -->
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navigation" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="channel.html">Channel</a></li>
       <li><a href="games.html">Games</a></li>
       <li class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt=""></a></li>
       <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
       <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
   </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to hide? (what's the CSS selector for the item?) Also, there appears to be a lot more code than what is necessary to reproduce the problem. This makes pinning the issue down more difficult.

Comment: i was trying to just hide the logo on mobile viewport. Included anything that would alter the nav thus all the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [bootstrap's `hidden-xs` helper class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities):

```
<li class="logo hidden-xs"><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt=""></a></li>
```

Comment: Great, glad to help. If you feel this answer is correct, please accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @BryanJohnson up-vote for the answers that solved your query.

Comment: wont let me yet :(
my isnt high enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `display: none;` to `visibility: hidden;`